# Laravel 5.1 query string parameter not working in pagination

Tags: php, pagination, laravel-5.1, query-string

I am using laravel 5.1 pagination. But its not working. I guess the problem is accessing query string parameter.

routes.php

```
Route::get('blogs', 'front\FrontController@blog');
```

Controller

```
public function blog(Request $request)
{
    print_r($request->fullUrl());
    die;
    $blogs=Blog::with('User')->where('flag','!=','0')->paginate(2);
    return view('front.pages.blog_list',['blogs'=>$blogs]);
}
```

For url http://localhost/myproject/blogs?page=2

Result : http://localhost/myproject/blogs?blogs. Where it should be ?page=2 instead of ?blogs. I have also noticed that query string parameters are not also working in others page. Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need request? Why do you call die?

Comment: for debug purpose. I wanted to sure that if page works or not @DevinGray

Comment: almost sounds like a web server misconfiguration for how its handling the query string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason was .htaccess file.

Comment: What should be in `.htaccess` file?

Answer (score 1):

use `->appends(\Input::except('page'))`

`return view('front.pages.blog_list',[
  'blogs'=>$blogs->appends(\Input::except('page'))
]);`

Comment: Thanks @Ravisha Hesh. But It's not working. I dont know why I cant access query string :( parameters...

Comment: did you see your params when you add `dd($request->all());` into your method?

Comment: Yes @Ravisha Hesh. It does not show page. just Array ( [blogs] => ) .

Comment: leave `dd()` as I mentioned on previous comment and go to http://localhost/myproject/blogs?page=2 manually by clicking on this link

Comment: I tried manually and it does not showing page parameter @Ravisha Hesh

Comment: So how to do appends from vuejs/ajax. Like I want to add product id in query params and I want to paginate number of comments that one product have.

Comment: You can use `appends($request->all())` in laravel to include additional params in pagination, pagination object contains links to next and prev pages, use those for navigation

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/comments?cpId=3&page=1 this is my url, and it's not working, If I remove cpid from query string it works well. I am return custom array not query result.

Comment: got it, my mistake, It working perfectly thank you.
changes i made is $comments->appends(['cpId' => $pid])->links();